# Is it possible to insert dictionary with pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, pymysql

I have a dictionary with the same names and columns as in database. Can I insert it as is, without rewriting `INSERT INTO` statement with all column names typed by hand again?

**UPDATE**

The question is about `pymysql` capabilities. You are not required to write a code, building `SQL` statement from dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyMySQL is like any other [DB-API 2.0 adapter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/); parameters must be placed in a SQL query as positional or named placeholders. If you want to avoid naming the columns explicitly up-front, you'll have to generate the placeholders programmatically.

PyMySQL supports executing queries with a dictionary of parameters, when you use the `%(name)s` parameter syntax. To generate an insert statement from a dictionary, you could use:

```
def escape_name(s):
    """Escape name to avoid SQL injection and keyword clashes.

    Doubles embedded backticks, surrounds the whole in backticks.

    Note: not security hardened, caveat emptor.

    """
    return '`{}`'.format(s.replace('`', '``'))

names = list(dict_of_params)
cols = ', '.join(map(escape_name, names))  # assumes the keys are *valid column names*.
placeholders = ', '.join(['%({})s'.format(name) for name in names])

query = 'INSERT INTO TABLENAME ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(cols, placeholders)
cursor.execute(query, dict_of_params)
```

Comment: @Dims: why should it be? You can't always assume that you have the right columns to insert. What if you omitted required columns?

Comment: The same as I omit required columns in SQL

Comment: this worked well for me, but i needed to use `dict_of_params.keys()` instead of `list(dict_of_params)`

Comment: @DrewryPope: both give an iterable of the keys, and the outcome will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

I realise that this is a fairly old question but it was the top result that Google gave me for 'pymysql insert dictionary' so having spent some time trying to figure out the best way of doing this I thought that I'd share. This is my first post here (despite 42 years of DP/IT experience!!) so please be gentle with me :)

NOTE that this answer is specific to pymysql - as I understand it other mySQL/MariaDB connectors may handle the substitution of bind variables differently (although it should be possible to adapt the join parameters on the VALUES to produce whatever format is required).

Assuming the dictionary described by the OP is held in a variable called data, say something like this:

```
data = {'season' : 60, 'game' : 10, 'player' : 'JS1', 'runs' : 18}
```

and that we have an existing pymysql write enabled connection in variable writer, then this generic approach should achieve the desired result:

```
   writer.begin()
   try:
      with writer.cursor() as insert_cursor:
         sqlcmd = (
          f"INSERT INTO Scores ({', '.join(data.keys())}) "
          f"VALUES (%({')s, %('.join(data.keys())})s)")
         insert_cursor.execute(sqlcmd, data)
         inserted = insert_cursor.rowcount
   except:
      writer.rollback()
      print('\aScores table insert failed. Transaction rolled back')
      raise
   writer.commit()
   print('Inserted', inserted, 'row(s) into Scores table')
```

Better still if we expand our data to be a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [
 {'season' : 60, 'game' : 10, 'player' : 'JS1', 'runs' : 18},
 {'season' : 60, 'game' : 12, 'player' : 'JS1', 'runs' : 0},
 {'season' : 60, 'game' : 13, 'player' : 'JS1', 'runs' : 60},
...
 ]
```

then with a couple of minor tweaks we can use executemany to insert them all in one call:

```
   writer.begin()
   try:
      with writer.cursor() as insert_cursor:
         sqlcmd = (
          f"INSERT INTO Scores ({', '.join(data[0].keys())}) "
          f"VALUES (%({')s, %('.join(data[0].keys())})s)")
         insert_cursor.executemany(sqlcmd, data)
         inserted = insert_cursor.rowcount
   except:
      writer.rollback()
      print('\aScores table insert failed. Transaction rolled back')
      raise
   writer.commit()
   print('Inserted', inserted, 'row(s) into Scores table')
```